# .sh unexpected "fi (expected "then")

Tags: shell, sh

I have some trouble getting my .sh script working. I get the following error message:

```
power_toggle.sh: line 8: syntax error: unexpected "fi" (expecting "then")
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE='hyperiond'
if pgrep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
    killall hyperiond 2>/dev/null
else
    /storage/.config/autostart.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
fi
```

I have tried shellcheck.net, and it doesn't find anything wrong with it.. 
I have also chmod +x'ed it. The 2 commands work fine running them via a ssh terminal.

Hope u guys can help, because I am lost.

Comment: Don't see nothing wrong, and it works for me fine... Are you sure the script above is what you're in fact trying to execute?

Comment: The syntax shown is correct.  That strongly suggests that whatever script is generating the error is not the one you show.  (There is some room for improvement in the code — nominally, it is a good idea to use double quotes around variables in `pgrep "$SERVICE"` and definitely a good idea to use `killall "$SERVICE"` (so you can change the service without killing the wrong processes) — but syntactically, it is fine.)

Comment: I don't know what it is, I have trid that 100 times, check it many times. If I try "sh power_toggle.sh" it gives me the above error. If l try ./power_toggle.sh it gives me "sh: ./power_toggle.sh: not found".. I am using windows and uploading to openelec @ Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Check for DOS line endings; if you really have `then\r`, then the condition list of the `if` statement was never terminated.

Comment: BTW, if your script starts with `#!/bin/sh`, it's a POSIX sh script, **not a `bash` script**. Even if your `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `bash`, it runs in POSIX compatibility mode when so invoked (and in many modern operating systems, `/bin/sh` is an entirely different interpreter such as ash or dash). Accordingly, I've removed the `bash` tag.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I think this is meant as a Bourne script, not bash. As far I can see, the OP never claimed that it should be run under bash.

Comment: @user1934428, the OP originally tagged the question `bash`, hence my comment. And `sh` has been POSIX sh, not Bourne, for decades now except on some very laggard platforms (SunOS comes to mind) -- while Bourne dates from the 1970s, POSIX.2 was introduced in the very early 90s, so we're talking literally more than 20 years.

Comment: @user1934428, ...incidentally, it's trivial to check which of the two a shell implements -- in Bourne, `^` is a pipe character, so whereas on a POSIX sh shell `echo ^ echo` will emit `^ echo` on its output, on a Bourne shell it'll emit only a single empty line. [Which is why it's worth making the distinction between POSIX sh and Bourne: *The two languages are mutually incompatible*].

Comment: @siz, ...btw, there are *much* better ways to do process supervision than with this kind of cron job, and your typical modern operating system will include at least one of them built-in. Apple has launchd, Ubuntu has upstart (though I think they may be switching to systemd?), Fedora and very recent RHEL/CentOS have systemd, etc. A good process supervision system will wait for a SIGCHLD when what it's running ends, so it's able to respond *immediately* when the process it's supervising exits, rather than needing to poll over and over and over, wasting resources each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your line endings from Windows to Unix (LF only).

Comment: Unless they have mixed line endings the script should have thrown a warning or error for not being able to find `/bin/sh\r`.

Comment: @Mr.Llama, only if it were exec()'d rather than invoked from a shell (which will typically fall back to executing with `sh` or itself as an interpreter when the exec syscall fails).

Comment: `bash` doesn't process the shebang; a system call does. The first character is a `#` precisely so that the shell ignore the line completely.